# A sequence in $\ell^2$ having divergent norm

Tags: functional-analysis, limits

Let $\{v_m\}_{m \in \mathbb{N}} \subset \ell^2$ be a sequence in $\ell^2$ over $\mathbb{C}$

We know that 
$$\lim_{m \to \infty} \left\| v_m \right\| = \infty$$

Is it true that 
$$
\exists n \in \mathbb{N}:
\lim_{m \to \infty} \left| v_m^{(n)} \right| = \infty
$$
where $v_m^{(n)}$ is the n-th number of the m-th sequence.

Thanks

Comment: No. Take $v_m = m e_m$. Then $\lim_m v_m(n) = 0$ but $\|v_m\| \to \infty$.

Comment: tanks @copper.hat for your answer